Unique constraint with nullable columns in Postgres 14
I am trying to create a hashed column consisting of other column values to use as a unique constraint for a table in PG14. This is a simplified example of what I am going for:
CREATE TABLE test (
    id CHARACTER VARYING,
    code CHARACTER VARYING,
    "deletedAt" TIMESTAMPTZ,
    "hash" CHARACTER VARYING GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
(((sha256((COALESCE("code", 'NULL')::text || date_part('epoch', COALESCE("deletedAt", '1990-01-01 00:00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))::text)::bytea)::bytea)::text)) STORED,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Which results in this error:
 ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable

After reading some other stack O posts I understand that the issue with creating this generated column is due to the fact that the deletedAt column is timezone specific, thus not immutable since this setting can change. What I am trying to do is use the epoch date which I figured would not be timezone specific but I am still getting this error and adding in AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' was a bit of a hail mary.
I had also seen that Postgres 14 has a built in function called hash_record_extended which can do this hashing for me resulting in a bigint. This sounds great but I am curious on how to get my current case working.
Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Move the timezone coercion outside of coalesce():  (((sha256((COALESCE("code", 'NULL')::text || date_part('epoch', COALESCE("deletedAt", '1990-01-01 00:00:00+00') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::text)::bytea)::bytea)::text)) STORED.  Fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/3ag93vvh

What is the use case; i.e., what is the base problem that you are trying to solve? If the intent is to mimic declaring a unique index havingNULLS NOT DISTINCT (introduced in PG15), then consider declaring a functional index; e.g., CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_uniq ON test(COALESCE(code, 'NULL'),COALESCE("deletedAt",'1990-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')).

Thank you both for your comments! Both of these solutions worked and helped me resolve my issue, which was indeed to get around the case of having a nullable value in a unique index (pre PG15).

Moving the timezone coercion outside of the COALESCE solved my issue here.
(((sha256((COALESCE("code", 'NULL')::text || date_part('epoch', COALESCE("deletedAt", '1990-01-01 00:00:00+00') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::text)::bytea)::bytea)::text)) STORED

